# Exclude Text Value From VBA Autosort

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below to perform a sort upon before the workbook is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean) 
    Sheets("Input").Protect "password", UserInterFaceOnly:=True 
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input") 

        If .Range("B7").Value = "" Then Exit Sub 
        .Range("B7:AH400").Sort Key1:=.Range("B7"), _ 
        Order1:=xlAscending, _ 
        Header:=xlGuess, _ 
        OrderCustom:=1, _ 
        MatchCase:=False, _ 
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _ 
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal 
    End With 
End Sub
```

The code works fine, but I'd like to extend the functionality a little further and exclude the text value "Enter your name" from the sort, so the cell with this value in column B will **always** be the last row underneath all my data rows.

I've spent a good week or so on this trying to find a solution, but unfortunately I've been unable to do so. I've also looked at the Microsft site to see if their are any inbuilt functions in the 'Range.sort' method, but again I've drawn a blank on this.

I'm not even sure whether this is possible, but I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may achieve this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: My first thought (since it is only 1 but of data) would be to remove the "Enter your name" data value... then sort.... then re-add it back into the bottom of the data set. Obviously this isn't terribly extendable. Also if "Enter your name" is naturally at the bottom of the dataset, you could alternatively just exclude it from the sort range.

Comment: Hi @Pynner, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I would be very interested to see if it was possible to exclude this value from the sort. I just wondered please whether you could perhaps offer some guidance on how I can do this. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data you wish to exclude is at the bottom of the range you can simply "right size" the sort range to exclude it. use the `.end` and `.row` methods to figure out how much data you have

```
Dim EndRow as long
```

after the if statment add

```
'find last row of data
EndRow = Range("B7").end(xldown).row -1
```

the change the range to use your newly calculated end row.

```
.Range("B7:AH400")
```

becomes

```
.Range("B7:AH" & EndRow)
```

Comment: Hi @Pynner, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to my post and for putting the solution together. It's exactly what I was after. Kind regards. Chris